# Rails, ancestry gem, populating dropdown with two depth level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tree, ancestry

I installed ancestry gem successfully following instruction from https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry and my Categories table look like this:
**Categories**(id, category_name, ancestry, created_at, updated_at)
[image]

I want to make select based on parent->sub-category->sub-sub-category:
[image]

At this point with code(taken from https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/wiki/Creating-a-selectbox-for-a-form-using-ancestry) i can only manage to get following which is not correct.
[image]

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is wrong. To model this structure you should have ancestry column properly filled-in. It should contain whole path from the root node (ids of the elements) sepatared by '/'. For example for Watches it should be 5/13 so as it was displayed under Clothes (Id: 13)